# ColdFusion 9 Date validation?

Tags: validation, date, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I would like to validate date argument after user submits the form. My app is running on ColdFusion 9 and there is few built in functions like `isDate()` but this function will return true even for some funky date values. I have approached this way to validate my date argument:

```
<cfarguments name="myDate" type="string" required="true">
<cfset getMonth = Month(myDate)>
<cfset getDay = Day(myDate)>
<cfset getYear = Year(myDate)>

<cfif getMonth LT 1 OR getMonth GT 12>
    <cfset message = "Month value should be in a range between 1 and 12.">
<cfelseif getDay LT 1 OR getDay GT 31>
    <cfset message = "Day value should be in a range btween 1 and 31.">
<cfelseif ((getMonth EQ 4 OR getMonth EQ 6 OR getMonth EQ 9 OR getMonth EQ 11) AND getDay EQ 31)>
    <cfset message = "Month of April, June, September and November have 30 days.">
<cfelseif getMonth EQ 2>
    <cfset isLeap = (getYear MOD 4 AND (getYear MOD 100 NEQ 0 OR getYear MOD 400 EQ 0))>

    <cfif (getDay GT 29 OR (getDay EQ 29 AND NOT isLeap))>
        <cfset message = "Only leap year can have 29 days.">
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

I'm wondering if this way to validate date has any issues? I tried to split the date to Day, Month and Year. Then I was checking each if it's in the right range. I'm not sure if there is anything else that I should be looking for. I'm using US Date Format mm/dd/yyyy in my app. If anyone have any suggestions please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Are you allowing free-form entry of a date? If so, I'd suggest using a date picker instead. Moment.js (http://momentjs.com/) is pretty good and easy to implement.  Dates have been the bane of my existence for a very long time, and if you take away the user's ability to send you their interpretation of a date and force them to send you _your_ interpretation, you'll be a _MUCH_ happier camper..

Comment: Sorry. http://makingsense.github.io/moment-datepicker/ is a good datepicker that uses momentjs. Moment.js is used for the validation and formatting.

Comment: But then again, there are people like me that consider any form that can't be completed using only a keyboard to be crapware.

Comment: I would normally agree. But allowing free-form date entry is a headache-in-waiting.  If it wasn't for users, this stuff would be easy. :-)

Comment: And I can't test that datepicker right now, but I believe it will allow you to enter a date in the field and do the validation on it right there. I would also recommend being very explicit on the format you expect the date to be entered in. A lot of times, that will do tons to keep garbage dates from coming in.

Comment: And just for reference, I currently work with the US Army. The common format for dates in just about every application here is 2 Jun 2017. But 6/2/2017 is common too.

Comment: I have JQuery date picker on my input field for the date. Also I set the field to be read-only. User can enter the date value only with datepicker. That will take care of the front end format of the date. Plus I have Javascript validation that will check date format.

Comment: Then you can use a combination of isDate() and regular expressions for server side validation.

Comment: Why not simply use a input type of date?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something else you should be checking on the server side.  This code:

```
writeoutput (dateformat("Apr 31", "yyyy-mm-dd"));
```

returns 1931-04-01.  That's a perfectly valid date which passes every test in your question.   What you do about it depends on whether or not the year 1931 is valid for your application.

Something else to consider is that if a value like "fred" is submitted, then your first command, `<cfset getMonth = Month(myDate)>`, will throw an error.  That sort of makes the rest of what you are attempting unnecessary.

Things you might consider are:

- using datepickers instead of textboxes in your form.
- use `<cfinput mask="something">` in your form.  Mind you, this option is annoying
  if your pre-populate the field.
- javascript validation when submitting the form
- a maxlength attribute in your input tag
- instructions on the form

Personally I use a combination of instructions, pre-populating the inputs, `<cfinput validate="date">`, and some custom tags I wrote several years ago that simply use isDate().  It's not perfect, but it gets the job done.

Comment: what about isValid("USDate", myDate) ? I have tested this function and seems fine so far. I tried to enter 29 days for February for the year that is not leap and that was indicated to false as well.

Comment: Yes, it is pointless to use month(), day() or year() because they do the same thing as IsDate() i.e. Convert the date *string* into a date (using best guess), so they will have the same issues. If the input must *always* be in mm/dd/yyyy format, why not just split the string on the delimiter and use createDate(), catching any exception?